# How to import a file to a virtual machine over the terminal

Tags: apache, command-line, terminal

I have SSH access to a virtual machine and need to add the following text to /home/bitnami/httpd-vhosts.conf (an empty file I just made).

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName HOST_NAME
   DocumentRoot "/home/bitnami/APPNAME/public/"
    <Directory "/home/bitnami/APPNAME/public/">
        Options -MultiViews
        <IfVersion < 2.3 >
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.3>
        Require all granted
        </IfVersion>
        RailsEnv development
        PassengerEnabled on
        PassengerAppRoot "/home/bitnami/APPNAME/"
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I can append each line like so `echo "<VirtualHost *:80>" >> /home/bitnami/httpd-vhosts.conf` but that can get tedious. I'm sure there is an easier way for me to do this, like just upload the file to that directory from an external source. But I cant figure out the right command to do this.

What would I need to enter to replace the empty /home/bitnami/httpd-vhosts.conf file with a file that has the text above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ssh daemon` running on the virtual host enables the use of `ssh` and `scp` and `sftp`. `scp` can be used to copy files between hosts over the network via `ssh`.

On the host where the file already exists in current directory:

```
scp ./httpd-vhosts.conf bitnami@vmhostname:/home/bitnami/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

The source is the file in local directory. The destination is `login` `@` `hostname` (or IP address) followed with `:` and the path of the file onto the virtual host.

A prompt may eventually be printed with a question, answer `yes`:

```
The authenticity of host 'vmhostname' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is xx:1f:74:62:xx:82:cf:xx:e2:62:xx:6c:48:xx.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
```

The password of the user login may be eventually asked:

```
bitnami's password:
```

Finally a progression bar will show the copy in progress:

```
httpd-vhosts.conf                                     100% 3855     3.8KB/s   00:01
```